# How to href="/page" in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, angular12

Im new to angular., here is where im standing,

I want my nav anchor tags to have relative urls like `href="/page1"` `href="/page2"` Only reason im doing this is cause i want my page to load everytime. i know `routerLink="/page1"` is typically done in angular, but i want to have use href="/page1" only problem with doing `href="/page1"` is when i try loading the page directly from with a absolute url like `https://example.com/page1"` im getting a console log error
`GET https://example.com/page1 404` but the page is loading everything works, but still showing a console log 404 error ?

How can i fix it ?

Comment: It depends on module your component sits in and the base route of this module, as well as child routing in your **yourmodule-routing.ts**. [See example](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-setting-up-child-routes-angular-12/).

Comment: Why would you want to reload every time..? That doesn’t make sense..

Comment: This is for SEO and Event Tracking